# Why am I seeing a black screen? Did I not alloc something?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

In xcode, this is one of the views I have created:

[image]

If I run the program in the simulator, I can see this view fine.  However, if I create a UIViewController class and hook it up with this view (I confirmed this view is a UIViewController), this is what I get in the simulator:

[image]

Why do I get this blank screen?  How can I get the screen that looks like the first image?

Edit: code

```
#import "EnterLevelViewController.h"

@interface EnterLevelViewController ()

@end

@implementation EnterLevelViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView
{
    // Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Comment: Without seeing code, I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII There is no code.  I didn't touch the UIViewController class file

Comment: If you don't have any code, what "program" are you "running"?

Comment: Ummm xcode?  When I say no code, I mean I didn't add any code.

Comment: "I create a UIViewController class and hook it up with this view"  You said you did this, so how is there no code? No code no view.

Comment: @HubertKunnemeyer I updated my original post

Comment: You created this view in a storyboard? What does your appDelegate look like? Did you use the TabBarController template? Check your view hierarchy in the storyboard and make sure this view is set for the  third tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears from your code that you have uncommented the `-(void)loadView` method from the view controller, which is provided in the template.  When you do this, the controller will try to construct the view programmatically, instead of using the nib (storyboard).  Remove the empty method completely and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

just drag from the tabBarController to the new ViewController in the storyboard and when you let go, press the selection for relationship ViewController.

Here is a quick example of how to set it up with three tabs, one with your view:

https://github.com/HubertK/TabBar_Example

Comment: Wow!  can you please make a new file (UIViewController, go to the "Level" view in storyboard, and associate them?  When I do that, I get a blank screen.

Comment: Take a look at the storyboard in particular.

Comment: I did.  I already have it set up that way (well there is a UINavigationController before each of the 3 tab views).

Answer (score 0):

The storyboard that was part of your project at the outset already included a view controller and its associated view. You can see it in the storyboard image that you posted -- it's the icon at the bottom with the light gray background. That view controller was set up as the root view controller, and the code that came as part of the project template loaded that view controller and its view. That's what you were seeing in the simulator. When you added another view controller, you must have configured it as the root controller instead. Since it doesn't have a view connected to it (or if it does, the view is empty), you no longer see anything.